# String compare in SQL Server !

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table T1 and T2.I used Sql server 2000.

**Table T1**

```
ID   WorkerName      Group
1    Rahim,Karim        1
2    Kamal,Adam         3
3    Rahim,Karim        1
```

**Table T2**

```
WorkerID   WorkerName 
1          Rahim
2          Karim
3          Kamal
4          Adam
```

I want to replace Worker Name on T1 with 1st WorkerID on T2 Like this.

**Table T1**

```
   ID   WorkerName      Group
   1      1             1
   2      3             3
   3      1             1
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Misleading title.  If you're going to call your question "String compare in SQL Server !" Why aren't you asking how to perform a string comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update T1 set WorkerName = T2.WorkerId
from T1, T2
where T1.WorkerName like T2.WokerName + ',%'
```

Comment: Adam you are loosing the information with that query. After comma there is another workername which needs to be also looked up.

Comment: He only cares about the first name, the second name is being discarded.

Comment: Dude when I looked at it, he needed both the names, check the history its been edited since then.

Comment: Okay, but even the original question can be answered with a single SQL statement. No stored procedure necessary.

Comment: update T1 set WorkerName = 
  cast(T2.WorkerId as nvarchar) + ',' + cast(T3.WorkerId as nvarchar)
from T1, T2, T2 T3
where T1.WorkerName like T2.WorkerName + ',%'
  and T1.WorkerName like '%,' + T3.WorkerName

Answer (score -2):

You need to write a Stored Procedure which runs on table T1 for every record and split the WorkerName using comma separator and execute a query on table T2 to get the id for the workername and update the table T1.

Comment: Read up on Stored Procedures, String Functions in SQL, and Cursors

Comment: Nahid its not a simple query, you need to learn what colithium has suggested.

Comment: Why negative, my answer is correct. Please check the earlier question, its been edited since then....